# QGIS version 3.28 Firenze, does not have the Sentinel 2 log in and download option in SCP

Tags: qgis, scp

[image]

I do not know why it is like this: no Sentinel 2 log in and also Landsat log in to download data from the SCP plugin.

You can see in the picture that there is no log-in for both Sentinel and Landsat, and there is also no option to pre-process downloaded data directly from the Sentinel Copernicus website.

I am now downloading the last update of QGIS to see if it is working.

Comment: QGIS plugin technical issues are best raised on the issue tracker for that plugin so they can be dealt with by the developer: https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues